# How to show that any non-trivial subgroup of G is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

My assignment Question is:

Let G be a group of order pq where p and q are primes. Show that any non-trivial subgroup G is cyclic.

Now according to Cosets and Lagrange theorem, is state that the order of the subgroup must divide the order of the group.so  here pq/p=q or pq/q =p. But i donot know how to construct the proof.

Appreciate if anyone can direct me.

Comment: So the order of the subgroup is prime. What do you know about groups of prime order?

Comment: That's a strangely worded question! The trivial subgroup of a group is generally defined to be the subgroup consisting of the identity only. So $G$ is a non-trivial subgroup of itself, and not all groups of order $pq$ are cyclic.

Comment: @DerekHolt some texts define it differently and unfortunately things are not always consistent. In this case, it is clear from the content of the question what is meant.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I guess you are right, but I have never heard of the group itself being referred to as a trivial subgroup before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very nearly there. If you start your proof like this:

Let $H$ be a non-trivial subgroup of $G$. Then by Lagrange's Theorem it follows that $|H|$ divides $|G|=pq$, and thus, since $H$ is not trivial, either $|H|=p$ or $|H|=q$.

Now, to conclude the proof remember (and you can quote that theorem), that a consequence of Lagrange's theorem (and it would be a good idea for you to figure out the proof!) any group of prime order is cyclic. So, what can you now conclude about $H$?

Comment: @ Ittay wesis, if <p>=H or <q>=H, and H is the subgroup of G so this implies that G is cyclic?

Comment: $<p>$ is meaningless since $p$ is a number, not an element of $G$. The solution is staring you in the face right now, you just need to collect your thought. Look at the my answer. $H$ is an arbitrary non-trivial subgroup. Its order is prime. Every group of prime order is cyclic. So, what can you say about $H$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ord(G)=pq$ for two primes p and q. If a subgroup of G is non-trivial its order has to divide p or q (Why?).

Now consider a (non-trivial) subgroup U with prime order. Take a non-trivial element g of U and consider its powers $<g>$. What can you say about $<g>$? (Hint: Lagranges theorem!